# How can I make a text_field that is disabled until typed into enabled using firewatir?

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir, automated-tests, browser-automation

When attempting to setup a Job Title the "add job title" buttons are hidden until text is entered. Using the following code to add a job title the disabled button does not become enabled.

`browser.text_field(:name, "addJobTitleValue").set firstJobTitle`

[image: script referring to disabled button]
[image: the actual button that stays hidden]

Is there a way to set the text_field and have the button become enabled?

Comment: Please provide link to the page, if it is public, or relevant HTML, I can not read the text at the screen shot.

Comment: Zelijko Filipin, I don't want to sound like a smart you know what but you can always right-click and open the image in a new tab. For some reason it won't place the image at actual size. Let me know if you still need more information and I will get it to you. Thanks for your help on the issue.

Comment: I tried clicking the image and it did not open in original size, so I thought this is original size. Right clicking worked. :) For future reference: screen shots are great, keep posting them, but copy/pasting relevant HTML helps too. In that case I can copy/paste the code you have provided in HTML file and try on my machine. Now I have to type it myself.

Comment: what needs to be done to enable the field? When you are testing the page manually, you just click on the field and it becomes enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the watir-webdriver versus firewatir I was able to use these lines of code to enable the button:

```
browser.text_field(:name, 'addJobTitleValue').clear
browser.text_field(:name, 'addJobTitleValue').fire_event 'onclick'
browser.text_field(:name, 'addJobTitleValue').send_keys firstJobTitle
```

This has solved the problem to me and convinced me officially to start the switch to watir-webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that using one of firewatir's .fire_events would have had the same effect as the chosen answer, and avoided the need to swap over to watir-webdriver.

E.g.

```
browser.text_field(:name, 'addJobTitleValue').fire_event("onclick")
```

replacing onclick with the other javascript events, until one triggers the button to be enabled.

Without an actual page to experiment with, I'd guess at `.fire_event("onchange")` or `.fire_event("onkeydown")` or `.fire_event("onkeyup")` being able to enable the button you wanted to press.